# Why doesn't the socket display the result?

Tags: python, python-sockets

I try to print out this code and the command in Pycharm looks like as it was looping through the code and no result displayed, I said that because the terminal doesn't complete its task, and the dollar sign doesn't appear. I need to know if that code results in any output from it. this code is a copy of some tutorial hence it's not created by me.

```
import socket

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 5050
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(ADDR)
s.listen()
print('running')
conn, addr = s.accept()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(ADDR)
s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()

print('Received', repr(data))
```

Also, I need to know what is the relationships between (WSGI, ASGI) and their relations with the socket in python.

Comment: wsgi and asgi are 2 different standards for HTTP servers and are unrelated to the socket module.

Comment: `s.accept()` is a blocking operation, your code stop there and waits for a connection which never happans

Comment: when I'm reading some resources I was sometimes reading about WSGI and socket in the same place so, I thought that there's a relation between them sorry I'm very new to learn them so, I don't have any background about them. could you please send me any resources to learn WSGI and socket?

Comment: @Nullman s.listen isn't blocking, *s.accept* is.

Comment: @MedoAbdin Please only ask one specific question at a time per SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code following `conn, addr = s.accept()` never runs because `s.accept` is blocking. Move the client socket's code to a separate file and run it seperately.

Server code:

```
import socket

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 5050
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(ADDR)
s.listen()
print('running')
conn, addr = s.accept()
data = conn.recv(1024)
conn.close()
s.close()

print('Received', repr(data))
```

Client code:

```
import socket

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 5050
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(ADDR)
s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
s.close()
```